# SCSI Tape drive on ubuntu and centos

Tags: centos, scsi, tape

On ubuntu 12.10 I have those SCSI drives:

```
[1:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  TSSTcorp CDDVDW TS-H653N  0208  /dev/sr0 
[2:0:0:0]    disk    Generic  USB SD Reader    1.00  /dev/sdb 
[2:0:0:1]    disk    Generic  USB CF Reader    1.01  /dev/sdc 
[2:0:0:2]    disk    Generic  USB SM Reader    1.02  /dev/sdd 
[2:0:0:3]    disk    Generic  USB MS Reader    1.03  /dev/sde 
[3:0:0:0]    mediumx HP       C7200            162D  /dev/sch0
[3:0:1:0]    tape    HP       Ultrium 1-SCSI   E24V  /dev/st0
```

On centOS 5.9 I have those SCSI drives:

```
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      Hitachi HDT72503 V54O  /dev/sda
[1:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  TSSTcorp CDDVDW TS-H653N  0208  /dev/sr0
[2:0:0:0]    disk    Generic  USB SD Reader    1.00  /dev/sdb
[2:0:0:1]    disk    Generic  USB CF Reader    1.01  /dev/sdc
[2:0:0:2]    disk    Generic  USB SM Reader    1.02  /dev/sdd
[2:0:0:3]    disk    Generic  USB MS Reader    1.03  /dev/sde
```

[Loaded kernel modules on ubuntu.](http://pastebin.com/8XadPPde) 
[Loaded kernel modules on centos.](http://pastebin.com/xn5YHXuM) 
This is the same machine, with same adapter, but with different operating systems.

In both situations `st` kernel module is loaded, but in centos I don't have my tape library in lsscsi and in /dev/st0.

What might be the cause that this won't work on centOS ?

Comment: Did you try to [rescan scsi](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/LinuxP/SCSI+-+Hot+add,+remove,+rescan+of+SCSI+devices)?

Comment: I've tried to rescan scsi but this won't work.

Comment: Is SCSI HBA driver loaded?  Please post dmesg from both OSs.

Comment: It looks like the be2 scsi driver is not loaded on CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

The `lsscsi` output shows (in the first column) that the tape library (it's not just a drive, but a library with a robotic arm & drive) is on a different SCSI bus than your other devices; so you're missing a module...

Your loaded modules show a LOT of iSCSI modules on the ubuntu(working) side, so if you look at `lsscsi -H` on the working system, you'll see what controller #3 is, and you can replicate it on centos.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is your case, but i was having a problem with a TL4000 on Ubuntu 16.04. The autoloader was showing when using lsscsi -g but suddenly disappeared.

I just found out that, on the Library Type configuration on the TL are two options: Random and Sequential. I've changed it to sequential, thinking that it was going to force the Library to use the tapes in the numbered order.

This option make the changer disappear on the server. I tested change this option back and forth and everytime it is on Sequential the changer disappear.

Also, on drive configuration on the Library, is a option to set the Control path. When you have two or more drives, you have to choose on of the drives to be the Control path.

My `lsscsi` output now looks like this:

```
$ lsscsi -g
[0:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  HL-DT-ST CDRW/DVD GCC4244 B101  /dev/sr0   /dev/sg0 
[4:0:8:0]    enclosu DP       BACKPLANE        1.05  -          /dev/sg1 
[4:2:0:0]    disk    DELL     PERC 5/i         1.03  /dev/sda   /dev/sg2 
[5:0:0:0]    disk    DELL     MD36xxf          0784  /dev/sdb   /dev/sg3 
[5:0:0:31]   disk    DELL     Universal Xport  0784  -          /dev/sg4 
[5:0:1:0]    tape    IBM      ULT3580-HH5      H971  /dev/st0   /dev/sg5 
[5:0:1:1]    mediumx IBM      3573-TL          E.70  /dev/sch0  /dev/sg7 
[5:0:2:0]    tape    IBM      ULT3580-HH5      H971  /dev/st1   /dev/sg6
```